# Private posts within the user feed

Tags: getstream-io

What is the best way to implement private posts in a users feed so that when the user pulls their feed they see all content but followers only see public content?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to filter activities within a feed once you retrieve them from the Stream API. With this in mind there are a couple of ways you could approach this problem. First you could perform the filtering on your end, but you would have to store all info about private/public activities inside your database. Second you could use multiple feed groups to achieve this behavior, one feed group for writing public activities one for private activities on feed group that follows both public/private (the users feed form this feed group you show to the user) and to other users you show the private feed group.